# how to delete all lines with a particular string but not deleting the lines containing the same string in a particular section of the same file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, pattern-matching, text-processing

file contains the below lines:

```
UserName aashii
UserName drisha
UserName aashii
UserName harsha
UserName sampada
<Anonymous>
UserName drisha
UserName aashii
</Anonymous>
```

I want to delete the lines having the string `"UserName aashii"` from the file in unix without deleting the lines having the string `"UserName aashii"` under the section `<Anonymous>....</Anonymous>`.

I tried the command :

```
sed -i '/^ *UserName *aashii *$/d' -i $file
```

But its deleting all the lines having the string even the lines having the string under the section `<Anonymous>.....</Anonymous>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/<Anonymous>/,/<\/Anonymous>/{p;b};/UserName aashii/d;p' file
```

Output:

```
UserName drisha
UserName harsha
UserName sampada
<Anonymous>
UserName drisha
UserName aashii
</Anonymous>
```

---

> `-n`: suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>
> `/<Anonymous>/,/<\/Anonymous>/{p;b}`: in the complete range from matching line `<Anonymous>` to `</Anonymous>` print pattern space (`p`) and then jump to end of script (`b`) (no further processing of other commands).
>
> `/UserName aashii/d`: for lines matching `UserName aashii` delete pattern space (`d`) and start next cycle (no further processing of other commands).
>
> `p`: print pattern space

Comment: sed -n '/<Anonymous>/,/<\/Anonymous>/{p;b};/UserName aashii/d;p' -i file

Comment: `sed '/<Anonymous>/,/<\/Anonymous/!{/UserName aashii/d}' file` would also be an alternative. Or `sed '/<Anonymous>/,/<\/Anonymous/b;/UserName aashii/d' file`

Comment: @potong: Thank you for your hints.

Comment: @cyrus - what is exactly the meaning of this command. Can you break up the meaning?

Comment: Also i think sed doesnt go same with all unix flavours.. in fedora it worked but not going with few other flavours

Comment: @aashii: I've updated my answer. This should work with every GNU sed.

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

```
awk '/<Anonymous>/,/<\/Anonymous>/ {print;next} !/UserName aashii/' file
```

Which returns:

```
UserName drisha
UserName harsha
UserName sampada
<Anonymous>
UserName drisha
UserName aashii
</Anonymous>
```

That is, print if it is either part of the [range expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) or does not contain `"UserName aashii"`.

Comment: your command is working too but i need to edit the same file with the output. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just say `awk '...' file > new_file && mv new_file file`.